# Using files in a child theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a WordPress site in which I am using a theme called OneEngine which uses the Aqua Layout builder. This comes with a variety of pre-made layout blocks.

The only issue I have is that by default each element is `col-md-12` which doesn't give me much in the way of fine control.

So I thought I'd create some new blocks for `col-md-6`, `col-md-3` etc

I created a child theme with the usual things

- `style.css`
- `functions.php`

  The Layout builder plugin is in this location:

`/wp-content/themes/oneengine/plugins/pagebuilder`

My child theme:

`/wp-content/themes/oneengine-child/plugins/pagebuilder`

So, in my child theme I made a copy of the plugins folder to make my changes, however the site does not acknowledge the changes in my child theme like it does with CSS

Essentially I want my site to use the plugins within the child theme.

Comment: your theme have child theme, i mean your theme author provide child theme ? if have use that and override the files

Comment: have you been activated the child theme on your admin -> themes ?

Comment: Yes, the child theme is activated